# Make content visible only to author in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, visibility, private, user-generated-content

I want to allow members of a Drupal website to upload their own content to the site (something like a blog post or questionnaire), but have it visible only to themselves (hidden from other members with the same role). The idea is to have them store some personal content that other members don't need to see, but that only the author member would need to see (or have access to) when using the site.

What modules would I need to use? Or how could I go about setting that up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this easily with http://drupal.org/project/content_access

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you've already solved this problem, but I recently did something similar with a shared blog in Drupal 7. I wanted users to have both private and public blog posts. I used the Save Draft module (http://drupal.org/project/save_draft) to add an extra button to the content editing screen, which I called Save (Unpublished) rather than "Save Draft" -- I used the String Overrides module to make that happen (http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides). In the admin panel for permissions, Authenticated users were granted to right to view and edit their own unpublished items. Users could thus save their blog posts in a way that others could not see them. Then I used Views (http://drupal.org/project/views) to create a list view that used the criteria content type = blog, state = unpublished, and content author = current user. This gives users a list of their unpublished blog posts.

Answer (score 0):

The https://drupal.org/project/view_own module handles this exactly the way you are looking for.